# Ruby on Rails - Unable to add "".jpg" file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to the Ruby on Rails.

I want to add ".jpg" file under the /Public/Images folder.

When I navigate to the add New page, I don't see the Picture Format in the menu.

Comment: Please provide more information.  What do you mean by the 'add New page'?

Comment: Right click on the Public/Images folder - > New -> Other 
When I have to add a CSS file, I follow these steps. Similar way I am trying to add a ".jpeg" file.

Comment: Given that I understand you correctly, this is not Rails related (or anyhow programming related either and should probably be moved). Someone correct me, but as far as I know you can't create any other files the way described than text files. CSS is basically a text file with a different extension, but you won't be able to create an image (such as a jpg file) from thin air. Use an application such as Photoshop to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the respone. In my CSS file, I have some logos to be displayed. And these images are suppose to be saved in Public/Images folder. 
So it means I cannot display logos or any other images?

Comment: Why should you add it by editor itself? You can add an image you have to the `{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/` folder directly(in the file system). and you can give the name in the CSS file

Comment: If you want help with a specific editor please mention with editor/IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with rails3.1 or next of that, there is an **app/assets/images** folder in your application directory. And there is a default image **rails.png** available.

Add any images over there and use them as follows:

```
<%= image_tag "/assets/rails.png"%>
```